# jQuery - Datepicker not pulling up on first load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this [page](http://slacklog.heroku.com/signup/question1) and this [page](http://slacklog.heroku.com/signup/question1) that i have datepickers on them using the jquery ui datepicker. It works well sometimes but when i first click on the field on occasions nothing happens at all. Cant seem to figure out why. Here is my code

My html

```
<input type="text" value="" size="30" name="report[start_date]" id="report_start_date" autocomplete="off" class="hasDatepicker">
```

jQuery

```
$('#report_end_date').datepicker();

$('#report_start_date').datepicker();
```

The code is simple enough but its not making sense...any ideas

Comment: Works reliably for me. You set it so that you have to click the image to activate it. Are you sure you're clicking the image? Maybe you're just clicking in the input field and expecting it to show. If so, your code has to change....

Comment: try now...i pushed the latest code

Comment: Still, works for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: firefox....is it working when you click the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of your page you have

```
document.getElementById('report_start_date').focus();
```

This focuses the element, but does not trigger the datepicker. You have to manually click it.

Try it, click away to unfocus, then click to refocus and it'll work.

To trigger the datepicker programmatically, use this:

```
$('#report_start_date').datepicker('show');
```